# nodejs send html file to client

Tags: node.js, express, html-rendering

I use this function to send a html file to the client, but in the client, I get nothing (blank page) without error. Is something wrong? please help.

```js
    var express = require('express'); 
    var fs = require('fs');
    var app = express();
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express); 
    app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/views/test.html', 'utf8', function(err, text){
        res.send(text);
    });
    var port = process.env.PORT || 80;
    var server = app.listen(port);
    console.log('Express app started on port ' + port);
```

My test.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          <style something here </style>
          <title>Test</title>
          <script src="..."></script>
       </head>
    <body>
        <div> Somthing here </div>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //something here
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is that all your code?

Comment: @mihai I have just edited

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Try your code like this:

```
var app = express();
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('views/test.html', {root: __dirname })
});
```

1. Use [res.sendFile](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) instead of reading the file manually so express can handle setting the content-type properly for you.
2. You don't need the `app.engine` line, as that is handled internally by express.

Comment: Why is that second parameter {root: __dirname } needed ?

Comment: it works to serve index.html this way, but if this file depends on assets, which are located nearby, I get errors. `GET http://localhost:3000/vendor/polyfill.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`. how to resolve that?

Answer (score 6):

you can render the page in [express](https://expressjs.com/) more easily

```
 var app   = require('express')();    
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
 
    app.get('/signup',function(req,res){      
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/signup.html'));
    });
```

so if u request like `http://127.0.0.1:8080/signup` that it will render signup.html page under views folder.

Comment: Side note - you're missing `path.join` with string concatenation. You probably meant `path.join(__dirname, 'signup.html')`. If you just contact the two with the `+` operator the call to `path.join` is pointless, as it's executed on a single argument.

Answer (score 4):

After years, I want to add another approach by using a **view** engine in `Express.js`

```
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    var html = fs.readFileSync('./html/test.html', 'utf8')
    res.render('test', { html: html })
    // or res.send(html)
})
```

Then, do that in your `views/test` if you choose `res.render` method at the above code (I'm writing in EJS format):

```
<%- locals.html %>
```

That's all.

In this way, you don't need to break your View Engine arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

The "../" is considered malicious and will result in `ForbiddenError: Forbidden at SendStream.error...` exception.

The way to go is using a **path** module:

```js
var path = require('path');
res.sendFile(path.resolve('views/auth/success.html'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = express();

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/view/test.html")
});
```

Here `__dirname`, gives you the current path where your files are saved. So in `res.sendFile()`, we first tell our current location by `__dirname` + (then we locate the specific file which should we shown on the home page i. e ) `"vies/test.html"`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this simple process and send html file  ->
res.sendfile("views/home.html"); // don't use capitla latter F with sendFile  you must be use small letter f
example : sendfile();

Comment: use `` for code examples

Answer (score 0):

```
In Controllers -> use this in get all routes in index.js

To render html
const router = require('express').Router()
const path = require('path')`enter code here`


router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/../views/test.html'))
})








To render EJS:
In server.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.json()) 
app.set('view engine','ejs')


In Controller- index.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const router = require('express').Router();
const path = require('path')


router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
res.render('test')
})
```

Comment: Please do not format your entire answer as a code block.