# serving html files in node js using express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

actally i'm trying to serve a html file in the browser using node js and express. unfortunatly i can't get the correct appearence of the html file.

here is the code :

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
// Chargement du fichier index.html affiché au client

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./table.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {

        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(content);
    });
});
```

Comment: `res.end(content);` should be `res.send(content);` isn't it? well i don't see any expressjs code here.

Comment: You didn't run the server using `server.listen(PORT);`.

Comment: Like this is repost from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345936/nodejs-send-html-file-to-client

Comment: i did run the server using server.listen(PORT);

Comment: @Jai the expresse code is in the end of the app.js . it is there i just posted the creation of the server and the call of the file.

Answer (score 2):

To send a single file for a specific route use the [`res.sendFile()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) function.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var path = require('path');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('path/to/my/file.html'));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

In case you want to serve all files in a directory use the [`express.static()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) middleware

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('path/to/my/directory'));

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

With express u can do something like

```
//init the app to extend express
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
//inside the http callback
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
   app.use(express.static("./file"));
})
server.listen(8000);
```

Comment: where does your file live?...You must have your static files in a directory and serve them using express static

Comment: my file is in the /views. i changed the path of serving the file to "/views/table.html" and it is not working

Comment: No it should be express.static("views/table.html").....given that views is in the same path where ur server.js is in