# I am trying to send an html file as a response in my simple express server route to "/" using res.sendFIle, but it is not seeming to work

Tags: node.js, express, dirname

This is the code I have so far for my router. Just a basic GET request to the root of localhost:3000.

```js
function fileSending(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
};

app.get("/", fileSending);
```

I have also tried importing path and using the path.join method:

```js
let express = require("express");
let path = require("path");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views", "index"))
});

module.exports = app;
```

update:
Have also tried suggestions from another post. Still not seeming to render my html page on localhost. Getting this error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
> '/Users/loganaaron/Desktop/FreeCodeCamp/boilerplate-express/views/index'

My file structure relevant to this is as follows:
|-- views
|   -- index.html
|myApp.js (express route)

I have also tried:

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("views/index.html", { root: __dirname })
});
```

And:

```js
app.get("/", (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("/views/index.html"))
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs send html file to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345936/nodejs-send-html-file-to-client)

Comment: What does "not seeming to work" actually mean?

Comment: What do you mean by importing the path

Comment: I imported the path module in order to use the path.join() method. I forgot to include the import in the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

looking at this error i once add it when i was learning Backend Development and Apis on freeCodeCamp that time i was using replit so i just deleted the repl and used the replit starter project specified in the tutorial and i used this code

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
const absolutePath = __dirname + "/views/index.html";
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(absolutePath);
});
module.exports = app;
```