# Node.js http module problem - when i read my file and opened in local host , the file i gave to read is not executed but instead variable name

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

***JavaScript***
***As you can see, i tried to read (1.html) but i got the variable (fileContent) as the result in localhost.***

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require("fs")
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync('1.html')

const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/html'});
    res.end('1.html')
})

server.listen(80, '127.0.0.1',()=>{
    console.log(`Server running at http://${ "127.0.0.1"}:${80}/`);
})
```

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs send html file to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345936/nodejs-send-html-file-to-client)

Answer (score 1):

You set content-type as text/plain and wrote string in res.end().

Set ('Content-type': 'text/html') and res.end(fileContent) where fileContent is variable you set for reading html file.

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync("1.html");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "text/html" });
    res.end(fileContent);
});

server.listen(80, "127.0.0.1", () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${"127.0.0.1"}:${80}/`);
});
```

Comment: I did, but same result, no differences.

Comment: did you copy this code?

Comment: No i wrote it. But the core concept is of another. Not running code and copying are related though?

Comment: I mean copy & paste my code, it works! Idk where you stuck, but https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp try using this method 